# I find X to be Y vs. I find that X is Y

Tags: difference

I wonder whether there exists any difference between the following two sentence structures:

- I find X **to be** Y
- I find **that** X **is** Y

Example:

- I find the research literature not **to be** optimally organized.
- I find **that** the research literature **is** not optimally organized.

Do they carry a similar meaning, and can they be used interchangeably?

Comment: I guess the former is more formal, that's all that's crucial. But a native is maybe finding more subtleties.

Answer (score 1):

To me, they have essentially the same meaning.  The difference is subtle, but I think "I find X to be Y" has a slight suggestion that this is your personal opinion, whereas "I find that X is Y" suggests more that it is a fact you have discovered.  Otherwise, "I find that X is Y" is simpler to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

This issue [has been covered on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/i-think-him-to-be-about-50-or-i-think-he-is-about-50), but it's worth noting the first comment to the question in that link - *This is a question about an obscure feature of English that makes no sense*.

Paraphrasing part of [a comment from one of our most knowledgeable contributors on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/i-think-him-to-be-about-50-or-i-think-he-is-about-50#comment113207_57816)...

> ***think*** does allow an infinitive complement with Raising to Object, provided it's passivized:
>    *He is thought to be about 50* is grammatical,
>    but
>    *I think him to be about 50* isn't passive, so it's "ungrammatical" (according to *some* "grammarians")

Besides OP's ***find*** and my ***think***, several other verbs can accept an "infinitive complement" (*X to be Y*). But not all verbs work in all cases, and there's no simple rule, and no universal agreement on what is or is not "acceptable". Whereas the equivalent *find/think/know/suspect **[that] X is Y*** is always okay.

My advice for *learners* is simply to ignore this (increasingly, *outdated*) construction. It should be easy enough to *understand* the usage, but I don't see much point in trying to *produce* it yourself. It's never necessary, so why take the risk of getting it wrong?