# Is find + noun + noun possible?

Tags: sentence-construction, ellipsis

I don't know whether I can use the construction "find + noun + noun" the way it is used in the following sentence.

> Do you find "behoove" an archaic word?

Is this sentence possible?

I am NOT asking about "find + noun + adjective" or "find + noun + to be noun/adjective".

Comment: Yes. Do you find Mary an attractive girl? Do you find chicken a palatable food? Do you find _Dombey and Son_ an interesting book? Do you find ELL Stack Exchange a helpful site?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I say 'find...interesting' or 'find...to be interesting'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/63009/should-i-say-find-interesting-or-find-to-be-interesting) Also [I find X to be Y vs. I find that X is Y](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/47119/i-find-x-to-be-y-vs-i-find-that-x-is-y) and [I found the box to be empty](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/153207/i-found-the-box-to-be-empty)

Comment: Note that *I **find** something [to be] ADJ* is a relatively formal usage compared to *I **think** something [is] ADJ*, so you should use it with caution (if at all! :)  Also note that obviously it's a *figurative* usage essentially meaning ***to discover** [facts]*, so it won't necessarily work very well in contexts where what you claim to "find" is obviously a matter of opinion (it wouldn't make much sense for two different people to "discover" mutually incompatible opinions/facts).

Comment: @FumbleFingers. I am NOT asking about "find something (to be) adjective". I am asking about "find + something + something".

Comment: There's no meaningful difference between *Do you find "behoove" [to be] an archaic word?* and *Do you find "behoove" archaic?* Same with *Do you find Mary an attractive girl?* and *Do you find Mary [to be] attractive?*

Comment: I'm asking about a verb pattern, not its meaning.

Comment: Omitting the copula verb *(**is, to be**)* is more common with ***find*** than far more natural alternatives such as *I **think** you **an idiot*** or *He **considers** Susan **a goddess***, but there's no real difference in the extent to which you can just use an actual noun (with contextually strong "adjectival" associations) in such constructions rather than using the actual adjective directly (which in general would be the "safest" choice for learners).

Comment: Of course, I knew the sentence "Do you find 'behoove' archaic" was possible. But I also have in mind other sentences such as "Do you find him an idiot?".

Comment: >Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat? Does that mean that only this discussion will be moved to chat? I don't know what the "chat" is.

Comment: A mod might unilaterally move this comment thread to "chat", in which case I'm sure that you (as the originator of the post) would still be able to access and contribute to it. But probably they *won't* do this anyway - at least not while the thread contains comments primarily concerned with whether and why it either is or isn't a duplicate. But whether it gets closed or not, my advice to you is to avoid the usage as far as possible. It's dated and "starchy" in general, and it's *very* difficult to draw a clear dividing line between where it's "natural" and where it's noticeably "odd".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150602/discussion-between-kaguyahime-and-fumblefingers).

Comment: Kaguyahime, the system automatically prompts you to move to 'chat' if you have a long exchange of comments with just one other person. Yes, sentences like that are possible, but they sound formal and old-fashioned.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. An SVOC structure is possible and the complement may be a noun or an adjective or an infinitive clause with "to be".  In all cases the complement has a similar meaning to the complement in a simple linking verb clause such as "'Behoove' is an archaic word".

In many cases it may be common to choose to phrase with an infinitive to avoid syntactic ambiguity with the SVOO pattern in "I found him a cup"  (meaning I found a cup for him)

Comment: > Henrietta! How did find Lord Willoughby? ...  > I found him a perfect gentleman, but him and the gentleman went off together, and now they're getting married.

Comment: Waiter: How did you find your steak, sir? Diner: Well, I just moved the peas and there it was!

Comment: Thank you, James K. The fact that the verb "find" can take the SVOO pattern is familiar to Japanese learners of English, but the pattern "find + noun + noun" as SVOC is tricky because, as far as I know, all English-Japanese dictionaries only mention the patters "find + it + noun + to-infinitive" and/or "find + it + noun + that-clause". This is the reason that I started this thread.

Comment: @JamesK - Lord Willoughby and the gentleman? Getting married? Oh my!